# issues with Android app with screen going back to Top upon clicking adding items to basket

Tags: android

I created an APP for a restaurant using a there website in Andriod studio but have two issues

1. On the order page on the APP when I try to add item to basket screen scrolls back to top without adding item to basket. (when I tried to open the website on mobile it works fine on mobile browser i.e user can keep on adding items to basket)
2. when I select menu on website it directs me to PDF file which doesn't work when I used webview, I also tried using Intent but that didn't help

Please help and many thanks in Advance

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will open pdf in Browser

```
  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

this will open pdf in webview use either one

```
 Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(pdf_url);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply Akshay - and yes I tried them both that didn't work

Comment: the code you sent is written differently but they do exactly the same to what I am trying to do and thats not working for some reason

Comment: you are using  webView.loadUrl(); method for webview

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebview;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();

Comment: webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String url = "http://www.rotihouselondon.co.uk";
        mywebview.loadUrl(url);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new yourWebClient());
    }

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

Comment: R u targeting  devices naugat and higher only ?

Comment: private class yourWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient() {
                     @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

Comment: @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.equals("http://mytravelarmy.com/rotihouse/Roti-House-Food-Menu.pdf")) {
                    //view.loadUrl(url);
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
            }

Comment: not sure which was the best way to send everything so send it here - I am targetting jellybeans 4.1 and above

Comment: remove this annotation and try  
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

Comment: reason being @RequiresApi - Denotes that the annotated element should only be called on the given API level or higher.

Comment: Tried removing Annotation like you suggested but no luck :( still same issue